# Docker attribute meanings?

Tags: docker, attributes, mode

Where can I find information to explain these docker attributes under docker mode? I have checked everywhere but I can't seem to find any answers for them.

Comment: Your question is too vague : you need to explain what you call attributes and provide a few examples. You also need to explain what you call "docker mode", because this does not sound like common docker terminology (not like "swarm mode" for example)

Comment: Sorry new to it all and it seems I need 10 reputation to post the image I needed to make things clear. The best I can say is that it looks like. d----, -a----, d-r---. What does that mean? it's under Mode, then next to mode it has LastWriteTime, Length, Name. It looks like a cmd dir display.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still too vague.
Can you tell : 
1 - what are you trying to do : write a Dockerfile (ie an image), list images, run a container from an image, install Docker, etc.
2  - what command you type ($ docker ps , $ docker images ls , stg else?)
3 - what is the actual output of your command, and if it does match what you want, what was the output you expected? (I suppose "d----, -a----, d-r---" is only a part of the output. It looks like the output of "ls -l" but with an unepexected "a").

Comment: I think that the original poster was looking for an reference explaining containers, images or any other objects attributes, things we get while inspecting docker objects. Unfortunately, some terms in OP's question were misleading, like "docker mode".